# How do I store a fitted PCA so that I may transpose unseen testing dataset? I do not wish to keep the large training dataset on my CPU

Tags: python, machine-learning, pca, data-preprocessing, tinyml

I have a very large training dataset. My training dataset contains 1050 gestures, with each gesture containing 12,000 data points. Feeding our machine learning models with this many data points will result to a very slow performance and poor accuracy. As a result, I used PCA to remove irrelevant characteristics from a high-dimensional space and projected the most important features into a lower-dimensional subspace, improving classification accuracy and reducing computational time. Using PCA we have reduced 12,000 data points for each gesture to 15 PCs without compromising the information extracted from the data.

In the future, I would like to store my machine learning model onto an Arduino. An Arduino is a small chip that roughly has 256KB storage. My training dataset that I use to fit the PCA to is 225MB in storage, therefore not possible.

Is there a way to perform and fit PCA to my training dataset so that I can transpose my unseen testing dataset in the future on the Arduino without having to store the training dataset to my Arduino for fitting?

Here is my code to fit my training dataset

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

transposed_normDF.columns = transposed_normDF.columns.map(str)
features = [str(i) for i in range(0,11999)]
x = transposed_normDF.loc[:, features].values
y = df.loc[:,['label']].values

pca = PCA(n_components=0.99)
principalComponents = pca.fit_transform(x)

pc = pca.explained_variance_ratio_.cumsum()
x1 = StandardScaler().fit_transform(principalComponents)
full_newdf = pd.DataFrame(data = x1
             , columns = [f'pc_stdscaled_{i}' for i in range(len(pc))])
full_finalDf = pd.concat([full_newdf, df[['label']]], axis = 1)
print(full_finalDf)
print(full_newdf.shape)
```

Here is my code to transpose unseen data

```
pca = PCA(n_components=0.99)

newdata_transformed = pca.transform(in_data)
pc = pca.explained_variance_ratio_.cumsum()
x1 = StandardScaler().fit(principalComponents)
X1 = x1.transform(newdata_transformed)
newdf = pd.DataFrame(data = X1
             , columns = [f'pc_stdscaled_{i}' for i in range(len(pc))])
newdf.head()
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to fit PCA on a training set and reuse later on another program.
You can use `pickle` to save the model and load it.
Here is a code snippet for that:

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
import pickle as pk
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs

X, y = make_blobs(n_samples=10, centers=3, n_features=20, random_state=0)
pca = PCA(n_components=2)
result = pca.fit_transform(X) # Assume X is having more than 2 dimensions    
input = X[0]
result = pca.transform([input])
print(result) # output: [[ 25.27946068  -2.74478573]]
pk.dump(pca, open("pca.pkl","wb"))
```

After saving the fitted PCA, you can reload in another program and transform new input samples without loading the training data as follow:

```
# later reload the pickle file, no training data needed
pca_reloaded = pk.load(open("pca.pkl",'rb')) 
result_new = pca_reloaded.transform([input]) # X_new is a new data sample
print(result_new) # output: [[ 25.27946068  -2.74478573]]
```

When you compare `result` and `result_new`, you find that they are equal.

Source: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/55066/how-to-export-pca-to-use-in-another-program

Comment: I see that the variable pca is being saved here by pickle. But will this save the result (4th line) too of the initial X, (in my case pca being applied to the training dataset)? Therefore the training dataset doesn't have the be uploaded

Comment: I want to be able to execute PCA in such a way that I no longer need to fit my PCA to the training dataset on my Arduino. I can import an existing PCA fitting to transpose my new data (therefore no 4th line where X is my training dataset)

Comment: @Quine, sorry for the confusion, I edited the answer. Now its possible to fit PCA on your training data `X` and then save it. Then you load the saved pickle file and apply PCA on a new data sample `X_new`

Comment: So will I still need to do pca.fit_transform(X) in the Arduino script. Or can I now just load the PCA by pickle and straight away transpose the new data (X_new). Therefore not needing the variable X (aka the training data)

Comment: @Quine, exactly. No need for the training data once you load the fitted model on Arduino. To make sure of that, you can test it and compare the PC's